# How to update a 2D Array in C++ through a loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, multidimensional-array, reverse

While refreshing my C++ and going through a very simple 2D array exercise,
I stumbled upon this maddening "problem":

I want to flip horizontally each row of a 2D array, from:

`image = [ [3,2,1],[6,5,4],[9,8,7] ];`

to:

`image = [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9] ];`

Then things got weird (at least for this C++ programmer). This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    array<array<int, 3>, 3>  image = { { {3,2,1}, // row 0
                                         {6,5,4}, // row 1
                                         {9,8,7}  // row 2
                                         } };
    //Printing array:
   cout << "\nInitial list:" << endl;
   for(int i = 0; i < image.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < image[i].size(); j++){
            cout << image[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << " " << endl;
    }

    //Displaying computation with expected values allocation

    cout << "\t\t" << "Future allocations" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < image.size(); ++i){
        cout << "\n Row #" << i << endl;
        for(int j = 0; j < image[i].size(); ++j){
            cout << "\nimage[" << i << "][" << j << "] => " << image[i][(image[i].size() - 1) - j];
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }

//Updating values - code change: add assignment operation.
    cout << "\n\t\t Actual allocations: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < image.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < image[i].size(); j++){
            cout << "\nimage[" << i << "][" << j << "] => " << image[i][(image[i].size() - 1) - j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][(image[i].size() - 1) - j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

 //Printing result:
   cout << "\n";
   for(int i = 0; i < image.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < image[i].size(); j++){
            cout << image[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << " " << endl;
    }

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;;
}
```

Output:

```
Initial list: 
3 2 1 
6 5 4 
9 8 7 

Future allocations

 Row #0

image[0][0] => 1

image[0][1] => 2

image[0][2] => 3

 Row #1

image[1][0] => 4

image[1][1] => 5

image[1][2] => 6

 Row #2

image[2][0] => 7

image[2][1] => 8

image[2][2] => 9

Actual allocations:

image[0][0] => 1
image[0][1] => 2
image[0][2] => 1

image[1][0] => 4
image[1][1] => 5
image[1][2] => 4

image[2][0] => 7
image[2][1] => 8
image[2][2] => 7

1 2 1  
4 5 4  
7 8 7
```

Problem: The last elements of each row are not updated with the first elements' value of each row. The two elements of each row are updated correctly though.

What am I missing?

Comment: On the first iteration, when `j==0`, `image[i][j] = image[i][(image[i].size() - 1) - j];` sets the first element equal to the last. The original value of the first element is irretrievably lost. In other words, `[3,2,1]` becomes `[1,2,1]`; there's no `3` anywhere anymore. You probably want to [swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) the two values. Or, you could reverse all elements with a single call to [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)

Comment: Thanks Igor - I got caught in circular thinking... :D

Answer (score 0):

This loop

```
    for(int j = 0; j < image[i].size(); j++){
        cout << "\nimage[" << i << "][" << j << "] => " << image[i][(image[i].size() - 1) - j];
        image[i][j] = image[i][(image[i].size() - 1) - j];
    }
```

is incorrect.  You assigned one half of the array to another half. So the both halves are now equal each other.

You need to swap elements of the both halves. You could use the following loop

```
    for(size_t j = 0; j < image[i].size() / 2; j++){
        cout << "\nimage[" << i << "][" << j << "] => " << image[i][(image[i].size() - 1) - j];
        std::swap( image[i][j], image[i][(image[i].size() - 1) - j] );
    }
```

Another approach is to use the standard algorithm `std::reverse` declared in the header `<algorithm>` as for example

```
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//...

for ( auto &row : image )
{
    std::reverse( std::begin( row ), std::end( row ) );
}
```

Or if the compiler supports C++ 20 then the range based for loop can be written like

```
for ( auto &row : image )
{
    std::ranges::reverse( row );
}
```